# Reloading another user's page

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh, tic-tac-toe

Assume you have made an internet game of tic-tac-toe or sth that is played between players. So, when a player inputs 'x' or 'o' or whatever is the input, the opponent must receive it on his pc.

I know how to make this with timer. But I'm interested in making it with an event. I mean, when the input is given we catch an event. Then, this event is reloading the opponent's page and he receives the info.

Is there any way I can achieve it? And does it worth it?

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called [HTTP Server Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push). Usually, from what I read it is *not* recommended to use this since it seems to put a lot of load on the server which has to keep many connections open (for each browser that is connected).

So if I have to do this, I would stick with a polling scenario (timer) like you described, too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! So, I guess it is better to stick to the timer...